# Does PushPlugin works in PhoneGap 3.0 and beyond?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-3

I'm currently using PushPlugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) for PhoneGap 2.9, i want to upgrade my app to PhoneGap version 3.0, and i'm wondering if anybody knows if the Plugin is supported on version 3.0 and beyond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin extends CordovaPlugin and it should work with all latest version of cordova too. Yesterday there is a new version got released.

There is no majore changes so you don't need to worry.